# Android Studio - Error in launch emulator - Vulkan-1.dll

Tags: android-studio, vulkan

when I launch the emulator in Android Studio, the following two errors occur in the event log:

```
Emulator: handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
Emulator: cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
```

Someone knows how to solve them?
Thank you,

Marco

Comment: Have the same error. Logs after that error:
...Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: WHPX: Failed to get virtual processor registers, hr=c0350005 C:\Users\nilss\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: WHPX: Failed to emulate PortIO access with EmulatorReturnStatus: 64 C:\Users\nilss\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: WHPX: Failed to exec a virtual processor emulator: Android emulator version 30.4.3.0 (build_id 7104519) (CL:N/A)

Comment: hey there @marco94 you can accept my answer... It is correct one

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I met this situation when I upgrade android emulator to 30.7.5

You need to create

```
"advancedFeatures.ini"
```

inside android folder

C:\Users\YourUser.android\advancedFeatures.ini

put this text inside it

```
# Here's how to disable Vulkan apps to talk to the emulator.

# Add the following lines to ~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini (create this file if it doesn't exist already):

Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have the JDK installed.

Check it out with this command (for example, on the command line):

```
flutter doctor
```

If there is an exclamation mark or a red cross next to the "Android toolchain" line, then you do not have the JDK installed.

The solution to this problem is very simple:

1. Download JDK from [this link](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u202-b08/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_windows_hotspot_8u202b08.zip);
2. Extract it and rename the internal
   folder “jdk8u202-b08” to “openjdk” and copy it under HDD or SSD (so
   its path will be: C:\openjdk);
3. Set Some Environment variables
   (search on google if you don't know). Name: "JAVA_HOME", path
   "C:\openjdk";
4. To restart a computer.

This should help. Good luck!

Comment: I have adopt openjdk installed and it still throws those errors