# Android Studio 4.2.2 Cannot install HAXM Emulator Accelerator

Tags: android-studio, haxm

Emulators have been working find since v3.x in Android Studio for me on Windows 7.

Recently, it attempted to upgrade the HAXM and failed. Now attempting to start an emulator fails with "Could not start AVD". The message at the top of the AVD Manager says "HAXM device is not found. Troubleshoot.".

Clicking on Troubleshoot produces the following advice.

- Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings (*it was working before and my bios should not have changed, so I have not looked at this*)
- ensure that HAXM is installed propertly (*it is not; installation fails*)
- Try disabling 3rd party security software (*nothing has changed here; using only Windows Defender*)

If I go to "Tools > SDK Manager", "Apearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK", "SDK Tools" Tab, and attempt to install **Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) 7.6.5**, it fails. This is what I get in the IDE log file...

```
2021-07-20 17:13:21,636 [ 724014]   INFO - tools.idea.sdk.wizard.VmWizard - Parsing C:\Users\jjones\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\package.xml 
2021-07-20 17:13:21,655 [ 724033]  ERROR - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Failed to update status to COMPLETE 
com.android.repository.api.PackageOperation$StatusChangeListenerException: HAXM setup failed!
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.install.VmInstallListener.statusChanged(VmInstallListener.java:63)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.updateStatus(AbstractPackageOperation.java:508)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.complete(AbstractPackageOperation.java:207)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.completePackages(InstallTask.java:174)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallTask.run(InstallTask.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:935)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:442)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$null$3(ProgressRunner.java:235)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:629)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:581)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:60)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:235)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2021-07-20 17:13:21,657 [ 724035]  ERROR - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Android Studio 4.2.2  Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7486908 
2021-07-20 17:13:21,657 [ 724035]  ERROR - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: N/A 
2021-07-20 17:13:21,657 [ 724035]  ERROR - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - OS: Windows 7 
2021-07-20 17:13:21,657 [ 724035]  ERROR - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Last Action: Android.RunAndroidSdkManager 
2021-07-20 17:13:21,657 [ 724035]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - "Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (revision: 7.6.5)" failed. 
2021-07-20 17:13:21,658 [ 724036]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - Failed packages: 
2021-07-20 17:13:21,658 [ 724036]   INFO - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - - Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) (extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager)
```

I know there are dozens of questions here on this or similar topics. I have tried many, to no avail. Others seem not to pertain to my situation.

Comment: Install the newest haxm (HAXM v7.7.0 at https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases). If any issues will occur during installation, HAXM installer will show a detailed output of what exactly failed.

Comment: Thank you. HAXM v7.7.0 installed without error. Reboot. Start Android Studio. Pixel 4 API 25 emulator starts no problem. Starting any emulator with API 30 or above and it fails now with "The emulator process ... was killed." If I look at SDK Tools TAB it still says "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer) 7.6.5 Not Installed." Also, now ever since this started the qemu-system-i386.exe process (for API 25 that works) runs at 50% cpu 100% of the time!!! Something is all wrong and I need to get my emulators working.

Comment: The problem with the API 30 or above was due to vulkan-1.dll issue noted and resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68306692/2184214. Found the vulkan-1.dll error in the idea.log file for Studio. However, it and the other emulators are now using 50% of my cpu 100% of the time. Whether in use or not. This is new.

Comment: Correction. The cpu usage settles down after 2-4 minutes. I had never noticed that it spiked like this on startup for so long. So this may or may not be new. But at least it settles down after 2-4 minutes on a 8 core, 32GB computer.